# Adsense Temporarily suspended my account

Tags: android, admob

I use adsense for past two years. It's all good but now I'm suspended for 28 days for clicking own ads.

I know clicking own ads is bigg offence in adsense. Even I don't have any of my app in my mobile. Then how could I do this? Even I have good revenue for every month.

They added "You cannot appeal for this". What can I do?
This is not Fair I think

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the wrong place to ask: Stack Overflow is not Google Ad helpdesk. The only people who could help you is Google, not random strangers on the Internet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a technical question, but an issue with a particular service.

Comment: Sorry. But I'm really disappointed with adsense.

Comment: They detect this than it is definitely done and they caught the event again and again wether it is performed by you , tester, any of your family member, or any outsider but it will definitely happens that's why they closed your account(Please ask to the following nearer persons of you because it happens behind your watch) and not it will never gone e started again before 30 days or defined time period.

Comment: *Sorry. But I'm really disappointed with adsense* => and that's you reason for asking off-topic questions ?! *"You cannot appeal for this". What can I do?* => wait 28 days. Another cheater getting caught and feeling sorry, I'm not buying this whole victim thing...

Comment: Otherwise change the admob account and add the ad id of new one.

Comment: @2Dee: Who is cheater. I'm working with adsense for past two years. And earning good income. There is no reason to cheat when you are good. Yes may be someone can click on ad continuously behind or out of my range. How could I responsible. For example you have an app with adsense ad, then I click 50 ads every day. If they ban you what could you do? What's your mistake? That thing happened to me. It's not joke It's my life!!!